# HP Pavilion g6 WIN 7 freezes during automatic update

Tags: windows-7

My laptop was not used for four months.  Attached power cord and turned it on. Everything seemed okay except my Norton 360 icon was not on the screen.  I found Norton in control panel and reinstalled Norton 360.  It found another Norton product which it removed in order to install 360.  After shutting down the computer it warned to not remove power because there were 45 updates to install.  It froze at #35 for over 2 hours.  Manually shut off then restarted normally.  Appeared normal.  Shut off normally and received warning to not interrupt power during installation of 26 updates.  Stalled at #16.  Shut down manually.  Restarted with system restore.  Shut down normally and again automatic updates started on 26 updates .  first 15 passed in seconds and again it froze on #16 for 6 hours.  Shut down manually.  Weekend passed and now Im trying to get guidance via my desktop.  What can I do?  Please make it simple.  I'm 82 years old and not very computer savvy.

Comment: I'm not sure about your Norton 360 issue. Which other Norton product did the installer remove? As for Windows Update, can you see exactly which update it's getting stuck on? Try the automated Fixit utility from [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?kbid=971058) and see if it fixes the update issue at least, then we can deal with other problems if any.